# Make a SQL Form Post Data Correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, insert

I am new to the php & mysql scene, and am trying to input data from an html form into a sql database via php.  In the long run I will want to input/modify/delete such data, so if you have any links/tutorials, etc, it would be much appreciated.

The HTML Code :

```
<body>
<form action="addcustomer.php" method="post">
    <font size="3">
        Name :
        <input type="text" name="Name">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Customer">
    </font>
</form>
```

The PHP Code :

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$database = "my_database";
$username="user";
$password="password";
$tName="customers";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    //Sending form data to sql db.
    INSERT INTO '$database'.'$tName' ('Name');
    VALUES ('$_POST[Name]');
?>
```

Comment: http://us1.php.net/class.mysqli check that out

Comment: Please use `mysqli` or `PDO`, as the legacy `mysql` extension for PHP is deprecated. The advantage of PDO is, if you use bound variables, your user data will automatically be escaped in your SQL statement.

Comment: While there are some major issues with what you've posted here, you haven't asked a specific question. You will get a lot of useful help here but only when you structure your question in a concise and helpful way. For more information, check out the help section on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

CRUD (Create Read Update Delete ) is a common thing and you can find other good tutorials online.
You can check [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) tutorial. They Have everything you need under PHP Database section.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, I can suggest you reading about php and MySql. Second of all you have couple of issues here. The action **post** that performs on submit, puts everything in a form with a name tag in a superglobal `$_POST`. So you can't use this:

```
$database = "my_database";
$username="user";
$password="password";
$tName="customers";
```

As you don't have anything there. You only have one field in your html in a form with a name tag, which is this:

```
<input type="text" name="Name">
```

As I understand that this is what you are trying to achieve, to put inputs from the `html` `form` to the database.

Now in you PHP file you can read from the superglobal `$_POST`, like this:

```
$username=$_POST['Name']; //Notice that the `name=` here, is the exact name in your `html` input field
```

You can actually see what's inside `$_POST` by var dumping it: `var_dump($_POST);`

This is a start. See that everything is working and you getting all the relevant information from the `form` and then you can move to work on sending it to database.
Now for the database. You should not use `mysql` command instead use `PDO` or `Mysqli`. 
You can find more info here on how to connect to database using `PDO`:

> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/
>   and of course you can read the `PHP`: manual: 
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php